# JQuery cross browser opacity (fadeTo) IE 7 & 8 png

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, opacity

I know this topic has been addressed several times here, however my problem is different (or possibly I missed it somewhere?).

My issue is that I need a cross browser way to set opacity and have it not show a black background on the transparent pngs (IE7 and 8).

Several here suggested:

```
$(this).fadeTo(0, 0.5);
```

however like I said above.. it displays black on the png.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with `fadeTo`, which is about the overall opacity of an element. Basically, what you have to do is get IE to understand the alpha channel of PNGs *at all* so it understands the bits that should be transparent, which requires some IE-specific CSS:

```
img {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(...);
}
```

Details (just a couple of links; but if you search for "IE" "png" "transparency" you'll find a huge amount of information):

- [MS KB#294714](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714)
- [Transparent PNGs in IE6](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6) (applies to later versions as well)

Comment: `+1` - That's bugged me for ages now, I'm glad there's a workaround.

Comment: Thank you.  Close!  I still get a black border around the image.  Any ideas?